# Stackblitz: How to import Bootstrap CSS framework

Tags: angular

I just found the amazing **Stackblitz** online VS Code editor.
I created an Angular project and under dependencies installed the Bootstrap CSS framework but how should I import Bootstrap in to my project?
Usually I do it by adding this line of code to **angular-cli.json**:

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

But how does it work on Stackblitz?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Angular you shouldn't be using boostrap since it depends on jQuery and using jQuery in angular is bad practice. You need to use their angular version called ngBoostrap.

Answer (score 44):

In dependencies add "bootstrap" then click enter.

then write following line in **styles.css** in `src` folder

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: It seems that this imports the Bootstrap CSS but fonts are still missing. So that for example  glyphicon glyphicon-heart results in an empty square. Console is saying: Failed to decode downloaded font

Answer (score 13):

try this :

**style.css**

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

It will load all your glyphicon icons

Answer (score 6):

In angular.json:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
],
```

For me works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open styles files at: **src/styles.css**
2. Add this line: `@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');`
3. Click **DEPENDENCIES** menu at left of screen. There is an input says: *'enter js/css cdn url'*
4. Write: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js` and hit enter.
5. Write :
   `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js` and hit enter.

Now you can use most of the [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) component like [buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/) and [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) etc...

Comment: did they change something about step 2? It just says "enter package name" and when I enter the URL I get "Unable to find package"

Comment: @bersling I'm wondering myself. Have you found anything? I only found a question posted in the StackBlitz project: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/809

Comment: Is it possible to include cdnj file to stackblitz project? I couldn't add this file using dependencies menu: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-full.js

Answer (score 4):

Quite an old question but anyway this will be helpful for any one looking to include bootstrap in Stackblitz.

**Step 1:**
Go to app.module.ts and write

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Stackblitz will automatically prompts you for installing ng-bootstrap module.

**Step 2:**
Add NgbModule in imports array.

```
imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgbModule ],
```

**Step 3:**
In your styles.css

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Now you should be getting glyphicons in your Angular project.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enter **bootstrap** at the **enter package name** input field of **Dependencies** section.
2. Add "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" to the styles section of **angular.json** file.

Answer (score 2):

Check this StackBlitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkc7ix?file=styles.css

It does have a angular-cli.json file and a style.css file

angular-cli.json :

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "styles": ["styles.css"]
  }]
}
```

style.css :

```
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line of code in styles.css under src

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

So to have the latest version of Bootstrap go to

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/
```

Search for CSS CDN link, from that link copy the version (in my case 4.5.0) and replace it with the above import statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1 : Enter Package Name (It will be available Left Side down Corner)
          > Bootstrap

Step 2 : Import Bootstrap into Project Here We have mainly 2 way

         1.Import in Style.css 
           **@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';**

              ## OR ## 

         2.Import in a Angular.Json  
           **"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",**
```