# I am unable include bootstrap into my angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

```
I have included bootstrap-beta npm package and styles.css page i have included the below code.
 @import '~bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'; and in angular-cli.json page 
{
  "apps": [{
    "styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.css"
    ]
  }]
}
but it showing cannot find files. any body help me to get resolve this problem. Below is my Code URL
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-ex-fv3rm4

[image]

Comment: is it only with stackblitz?

Comment: Why dont you use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: I have included the package "bootstrap-beta". it is same as like "npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta". after ingrating code to styles and angular-cli , it showing cannot find files

Comment: The path will be `../node_modules/bootstrap-beta` etc from the looks of it (check inside your node modules directory)

Comment: i have attached the screen shot given by npmjs documentation folder path. URL is https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-beta

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes. i try to integrating bootstrap on stackblitz

Comment: I've just installed this package, and checked on that stackblitz, and they've both created a dir called `bootstrap-beta`. The reason for that documentation is that it comes from the bootstrap github page. NPM will create a directory with whatever the package name is, in this case `bootstrap-beta`

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054530/8800147

Comment: @user184994,@br.julien - no luck bros

Comment: @ramu yes posted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, you need to use the following path:

```
../node_modules/bootstrap-beta/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Here is a working stackblitz, with thanks to @br.julien for the tip on getting it to work in Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-ex-fxyg5b

Comment: It's working like a charm, it's my bad, due to path problem it's not working. i have changed bootstrap to bootstrap-beta and added dist to path. it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use the node_modules path in your case in angular-cli.json.

You can directly import the boostrap reference in styles.css  as

```
@import '~bootstrap-beta/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

and then add styles.css in angular-cli.json

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "styles": ["styles.css"]
  }]
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-ex-qctym2?file=.angular-cli.json)**